# Remix.run 1.19.3 and Helmet

Tags: next.js, remix.run

I was wondering if it would be possible and beneficial to use Helmet in a Remix.run app.

If so, I would be glad if someone could give the an idea on how to implement it.

Helmet React - > https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet
Helmet Js -> https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Remix has an API for this : https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/meta-v2

Basically export a `meta` function in a route:

```
export const meta: V2_MetaFunction = () => {
  return [
    { title: "Very cool app | Remix" },
    {
      property: "og:title",
      content: "Very cool app",
    },
    {
      name: "description",
      content: "This app is the best",
    },
  ];
};
```

the meta function is provided data from the route loader as a parameter.
Don't forget to render a  component at the root.